# Extensionless URL with Spring MVC and Freemarker

Tags: spring-mvc, url-rewriting, freemarker

I am working on a project that involves Freemarker and Spring MVC and in the presentation layer all the pages have a ".ftl" extention.

Now a late requirement came up where they want me to remove all those extensions and make all the URLs extension-less. So for example if an URL used to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.ftl
```

they want the new URL to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/index
```

UrlRewriteFilter is new to me. Any help on how I can configure the rule will be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I have never used Spring MVC but in any MVC framework that's not a complete joke the public URL should refer to the MVC Controllers (Actions), not to the MVC Views. FreeMarker, Velocity and like are for View, so what does a template name (with or without extension) do in the URL on the first place? Maybe that's what you should look into first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a standard style Spring MVC setup, the best way is probably to change the `@RequestMapping` in all of your controllers to be like `@RequestMapping("/index")` instead of `@RequestMapping("/index.ftl")`  It's more work, maybe, than writing a bunch of rewrite rules, but it's definitely much less hacky.